# Java: how to stop a server (close a Socket) without an exception?

Tags: java, sockets, server, network-programming, ioexception

I've made a server which allows to join many clients.
However I have a problem.
I added START/STOP button which should start/stop server. But the code does not work like I want: connection isn't closed and code goes to the IOException "THIS IS PROBLEM" (in ServerLogic part).
Additionally clients still can contact with server.

SERVER LOGIC

```
public class ServerLogic
{

private static ServerSocket m_sSocket;
private static Set<ServerSubscriber> m_subscriberList = new HashSet<ServerSubscriber>();
private static boolean m_isServerRun = false;

private static class ServerLogicHolder
{
    static final ServerLogic INSTANCE = new ServerLogic();
}


private ServerLogic()
{}


public static ServerLogic getServerLogic()
{
    return ServerLogicHolder.INSTANCE;
}


/**
 * It starts listening of incoming connections from the clients.
 * 
 * @param port
 */
public void startListening(int port)
{
    try
    {
        if (!m_isServerRun)
        {
            m_sSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            K6s.getUiServerConsole().addLine(Config.LOG_START);
            m_isServerRun = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(Config.LOG_ERROR1);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(Config.LOG_ERROR1);
    }

    try
    {
        while (isServerRun())
        {
            new Thread(new ServerSubscriber(m_sSocket.accept(), K6s.getUiServerConsole())).start();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        /*
         java.net.SocketException: socket closed
         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
         at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
         at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
         at org.czarny.k6s.comm.ServerLogic.startListening(ServerLogic.java:69)
         at org.czarny.k6s.gui.K6s$2$1.run(K6s.java:138)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        */
    }
}


/**
 * Just close server's socket.
 */
public void stopListening()
{
    if (m_isServerRun)
    {
        try
        {
            m_isServerRun = false;
            m_sSocket.close();
            m_sSocket = null;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            m_isServerRun = true;
            System.out.println(Config.LOG_ERROR4);
        }
    }
}


public HashSet<ServerSubscriber> getSubscriberList()
{
    return (HashSet<ServerSubscriber>) m_subscriberList;
}


public boolean isServerRun()
{
    return m_isServerRun;
}
}
```

CLIENT SUBSCRIBER (not neccessary code has been removed)

```
public class ServerSubscriber implements Runnable
{

private Socket m_socket;
private LogComponent m_serverConsole;
private PrintWriter m_outComm;

private String m_subscriberIP;
private String m_subscriberName;
private String m_subsctiberLogInfo;


ServerSubscriber(Socket socket, LogComponent serverConsole)
{
    m_socket = socket;
    m_serverConsole = serverConsole;
    try
    {
        m_outComm = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendMessage(Config.MSG_HANDSHAKE);
}


/**
 * This method runs messages from this subscriber.
 */
public void run()
{
    String line;
    BufferedReader inComm = null;

    try
    {
        inComm = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_socket.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        m_serverConsole.addLine(Config.LOG_ERROR3);
    }

    while (ServerLogic.getServerLogic().isServerRun())
    {
        try
        {
            //do something here
    }
}
}
```

Button which handles START/STOP

```
uiStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            if (!ServerLogic.getServerLogic().isServerRun())
            {
                uiStart.setText(Config.GUI_BTN_STOP);
                new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ServerLogic.getServerLogic().startListening(Integer.parseInt(uiServerPort.getText()));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            else
            {
                ServerLogic.getServerLogic().stopListening();
                m_uiServerConsole.addLine(Config.LOG_STOP);
                uiStart.setText(Config.GUI_BTN_START);
            }
        }
    });
```

What I missed? 
How to properly close connection without any exceptions? 
Should I just before closing the Socket send to all clients some message with demand of closeure or just closing the Socket on the server should be enough?
Regards.

Comment: Could you please add the exception stack trace ?

Comment: Of course. Sorry, I've forgot.

Comment: Closing the ServerSocket which is in the accept() method will *of course* abort the accept() method with an exception. Its how blocking methods usually abort. You will need to catch the exception and within the catch block you need to decide if the exception was thrown *because* the socket was closed *or* if it has another reason. You could simply use isClosed() in the catch block, for example to make that decision.

Comment: Do you mean its normal and up to my decision is what I will do with this? Strange thing is client still can connect to the server even exception occurs. It looks like socket isn't closed because it is locked.

Comment: Yes its "normal" - youre closing the socket while its processing accept. The only way out is throwing an exception, since if it returned normally it would need to return an accepted socket by contract.

Comment: If you can still connect to that port, you must have more logic that starts another ServerSocket for that port again. After you called close() on a ServerSocket it will stop accepting connections. Or maybe you mean existing connections? These will *of course* continue to exist. Once made, a connection is independent of the ServerSocket that accepted it.

Comment: @Durandal - `Once made, a connection is independent of the ServerSocket that accepted it.` ---> One end of the Connection will exist, but, not usable at all, in case the server has disconnected(as the other point has terminated itself)! So, I believe your last line is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: I mean existing connection. After pressing button closeConnection() method is called: socket is closed and nullified (I hope). Hovewer all clients can send a messages to server.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful You misread my comment. I'm talking about the endpoints that got *accepted* by the ServerSocket within the same VM. There is no dependency. You are talking about the remote end.

Comment: @Durandal - Maybe, I still didn't understand what you want to convey. But, I just want to bring to OP's notice that  i) this one-end type of connection shouldn't be termed as connection, and ii)Even in same VM, the representation of two endpoints is distinct! Anyways, I hope you too resolve OP's doubts.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Well, 'Socket that got accepted by ServerSocket' is as specific as I can imagine. The remainder of your comment seems to go on further tangents only you can see. Topic closed as pointless.

Comment: @Durandal - Now, I got your point. You've been talking about the socket's accepted at the server side; whereas I've been talking about serversocket! Actually, OP asked about closing the serversocket, isn't it?Sorry, a misunderstanding!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful No Problem, just wanted to avoid an endless discussion which would be frustrating and fruitless for both of us. The OP *initially* asked about closing the ServerSocket *as far as I understood* but seems now to have extended the scope to how to close the already established connections to clients as well.

Comment: FYI: point of my question was rather "how to shut down server and close all sockets - no matter of the type - on the server side". I asked about Socket (recieved from ServerSocket.accept()) because this specific one throws exception. But if closing ServerSocket is connected with Sockets then I am also interested in ServerSocket.

Comment: @rainbow There has just been an extensive discussion concerning the fact that closing the `ServerSocket` is *not* connected with `Sockets`. Closing either has no effect on the other. You claim your question is really about `Socket`, but the stack trace you posted was from `ServerSocket`. Unclear what you're really asking, but all you have to do is swallow the exception if it was deliberately caused. NB Don't print stupid messages like "This is problem". Print the exception.

Comment: @EJP "This is problem" was only for purposes of this post (anyway I slightly modified first post maybe now will have more sense). In the moment of asking this question I didn't know there is difference between closing ServerSocket and Socket. This discussion has clarified this. Anyway I think now I understand how it works. Thanks to each debater.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I added START/STOP button which should start/stop server. But the code does not work like I want: connection isn't closed

That's because you're closing the `ServerSocket`, not an accepted socket.

> and code goes to the IOException "THIS IS PROBLEM" (in ServerLogic part).

That's normal. Nothing wrong here.

> Additionally clients still can contact with server.

*Existing* clients can continue to use their *existing connections*. If you want to close those, see next. No *new* connections can be created.

> How to properly close connection without any exceptions?

Shut them down for input. That will cause the reads to incur an end of stream, which should already cause the threads concerned to close the socket and exit.

> Should I just before closing the Socket send to all clients some message with demand of closeure or just closing the Socket on the server should be enough?

Closing the socket is sufficient. Sending an extra message doesn't add any value. The clients will get the usual end-of-stream indications from their reads, or an `IOException: connection reset` on their writes.

Comment: This answer explains everythig I need to know. Thank you.